# JavaFX bidirectional binding - FXML

Tags: java, javafx, binding, fxml

as far as i know, it is possible to bind  a property and read its value from the controller, it works fine with a readonly field like a label, but it doesn't work with a Textbox.

FXML:

```
<TextField text="${controller.userName}" />
```

controller:

```
private final StringProperty userName = new SimpleStringProperty();
public StringProperty userNameProperty() {
    return userName;
}
```

Using this strategy i cannot set the text box value from the user interface.

Removing the binding from the FXML document and adding a binding on the controller side works fine:

FXML:

```
<TextField fx:id="userNameTextField" />
```

controller:

```
private final StringProperty userName = new SimpleStringProperty();

@FXML
private TextField userNameTextField;

@FXML
void initialize() {
    userNameTextField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(userName);
}
```

but i don't like this solution because i want to decouple controller and FXML.

My question is: is it possible to have a bidirectional binding wihtout setting the binding on controller side?

What is the best design pattern for to connect my model with my presentation layer?

Comment: No. . . . . . .

Comment: Isn't having the controller and FXML "coupled" the entire point of the FXML/controller concept?  You cannot create the bidirectional binding you want with straight FXML either way, though.

Comment: then the suggested design pattern for a JavaFX / FXML application is MVC? or what else?

Comment: It is MVC. By right, FXML is the View and it shouldn't be concerned with the values, it is the job of the controller to ensure that the values are correct. So ideally, you shouldn't even do binding in FXML. Furthermore, the View shouldn't be aware of the controller in MVC, so that sample binding you gave is already a very very bad idea. Binding in FXML should be kept to binding between nodes inside what the FXML defined itself.

Comment: please @Jai repaly to my question so i will mark it as solution, tnx for you suggestion. I'm not senior using java and i really appreciate your response.

Comment: I'm getting into JavaFX just now and this all just seems like a very questionable design decision. I really can't see how forcing your controller to populate itself with GUI widgets in order to support bidrectional binding is even remotely close to "MVC", if anything it's MVP. How are you supposed to unit test your controllers? Implementing bidrectional data binding in the view was stated by the developers as one of their highest priorities way back in 2013, yet here we still are....

Comment: @MarkFeldman I've had this thought as well. We're currently over-engineering things by adding another class between controller and model, and V-C-VM-M setup. I'm currently trying to define the gui components in the controller, as suggested, but then binding these to properties also defined in the controller. So all methods and such in the controller just interacts with properties, and these properties then update the view. It means all my functionality doesn't depend on gui stuff, so I can unit test it, but I'm not super happy about this approach.